# When I print the array in unorder list, it will duplicate print on click event

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I am trying to create a "To Do List". When I add something it will show in the list.

My unexpected outcome is like the below and when I console it it will come as I expected:

- 1
- 1
- 2
- 1
- 2
- 3

But I wish it would come like

- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4

My code is below

```js
var add_input_txt = document.getElementById("add_input");
var add_btn = document.getElementById("add_list");
var show_list = document.getElementById("show_list");
var all_list = [];

add_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var add_input_txt_value = add_input_txt.value;
    if(add_input_txt.value){
        all_list.push(add_input_txt.value);
        var all_list_l = all_list.length;

        for(var i = 0; i<all_list_l; i++){  
            let li = document.createElement("li");  
             show_list.innerHTML += "<li>" + all_list[i] + "</li>";
        }

    }else{
        alert("Please enter first");
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="add_box">
    <input type="text" id="add_input">
    <button type="submit" id="add_list">Add List</button>
</div>

<div class="all_list">
    <ul id="show_list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're always appending every item to the list, even if it's already there.  One approach could be to clear the list first:

```js
var add_input_txt = document.getElementById("add_input");
var add_btn = document.getElementById("add_list");
var show_list = document.getElementById("show_list");
var all_list = [];

add_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var add_input_txt_value = add_input_txt.value;
    if(add_input_txt.value){
        all_list.push(add_input_txt.value);
        var all_list_l = all_list.length;

        show_list.innerHTML = ""; // <--- here
        for(var i = 0; i<all_list_l; i++){  
            let li = document.createElement("li");  
             show_list.innerHTML += "<li>" + all_list[i] + "</li>";
        }

    }else{
        alert("Please enter first");
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="add_box">
    <input type="text" id="add_input">
    <button type="submit" id="add_list">Add List</button>
</div>

<div class="all_list">
    <ul id="show_list">
    </ul>
</div>
```

Another approach could be to only add the new element:

```js
var add_input_txt = document.getElementById("add_input");
var add_btn = document.getElementById("add_list");
var show_list = document.getElementById("show_list");
var all_list = [];

add_btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    var add_input_txt_value = add_input_txt.value;
    if(add_input_txt.value){
        all_list.push(add_input_txt.value);
        var all_list_l = all_list.length;

        show_list.innerHTML += "<li>" + add_input_txt.value + "</li>"; // <--- here

    }else{
        alert("Please enter first");
    }
});
```

```html
<div class="add_box">
    <input type="text" id="add_input">
    <button type="submit" id="add_list">Add List</button>
</div>

<div class="all_list">
    <ul id="show_list">
    </ul>
</div>
```